# How to parse given types of string to list?

Tags: python-2.7, parsing

The user input string follows the pattern:
`{ 1, 2, 4, 6, 3 }`
`{ 2, 5, 8, 0, 3, 45, 5 }`

How to convert any one of the given user input to list of integers.

Maybe split can be used as in `A.split(', ')` but then we get,
`A = ['{ 1', '2', '4', '6', '3 }']`
but the answer, we want should be,
`A = [1, 2, 4, 6, 3]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way would be to strip the parentheses, split on commas and cast the types.

```
A = [int(x) for x in A.lstrip(' (').rstrip(' )').split(', ')]
```

The proper way to do this is the same way a compiler would do it: tokenize the input before parsing, using a library like [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html).

(Also, you should make an effort to do your own homework and learn to write proper English.)

Comment: Thnx and can you tell how to convert each member into int, in a shorthand manner

Answer (score 1):

replace `{}` to `[]` and use json module to parse:

```
>>> import json
>>> s = "{ 1, 2, 4, 6, 3 }"
>>> json.loads(s.replace("{","[").replace("}","]"))
[1, 2, 4, 6, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `try` and `except` to accomplish this. Basically you try to convert each character of your string to int, if successful then you append it to a list if Python raises an error -because cannot convert to int- then nothing will be appended. Maybe this is not the shortest code but it is definitely very readable.

```
s = '{ 1, 2, 4, 6, 3 }'
result = []

for item in s:
    try:
        result.append(int(item))
    except:
        pass

print(result)
>>>[1, 2, 4, 6, 3]
```